# Bode diagram from transfer function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, computational-physics, software

I struggle with how to plot a Bode diagram from a transfer function. I know that the pools and zeros change the slope and of the magnitude plot and the phase, but I do not understand where the magnitude should start. For example: 
\begin{equation}
H(s)=\frac{-s^2}{s^2+10s+100}
\end{equation}
can be written as 
\begin{equation}
H(s)=-\frac{1}{100}\frac{s^2}{\frac{s^2}{100}+\frac{s}{10}+1}
\end{equation}
and then I thought that the magnitude at zero frequency should be $20\log \frac{1}{100}=-40$dB. But when plotting it in Matlab using the bode function, the magnitude at zero frequency is $-80$dB so obviously I get something wrong. Can someone explain this for me?

Answer (score 0):

Do not start off at 0 frequency because you may not know where the important changes occur. Talking with perspective of circuits I usually start with the resonant frequency (OR cut-off if it does not exist), I then take 4-5 frequencies before it and 4-5 frequencies after it (Sometimes the resonant can be a problem for example in the band stop filter as log(0) is undefined so a few places left or right to it also gives a good plot)

If you have troubles finding the resonant/cut-off frequency then firstly convert your transfer function into the form where in the denominator, the coefficient is 1 where $ S^0 $ or the power of S is zero just like in your case 
$$H(s)=−1/100*s^2/(s^2/100+s/10+1)  $$
Now put $ S = jw$ where $j$ is iota and $w$ is the angular frequency in radians/sec. Now whatever coefficient is present with the highest power of S or $w $ you have to find some value of S or $w$ that the term also becomes a 1 for example if you choose the value of S=10 in your case, that term will become a 1